# Print ASP web page using VB or C# code, not javascript

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, printing, webforms

I am writing an ASP.NET intranet application.

The server it will be deployed on has all the printers I need added to it.

I want to be able to access the printer using the code behind and print the contents of a web page I have set up for printing.

I do not want the java script solution, we are using that now, and we cannot allow users to see a print dialog. There are other security issues we have with this because we are trying to print checks. Also would like access and control over the print trays if possible.

I am looking for something along the lines of this: 
http://forums.asp.net/t/587341.aspx?Access+Your+Network+Printer

Any help or references appreciated, been searching for 2 days haven't found much.

Comment: Printing is never fun. I always suggest you create a report and send it to the printer. With ASP, you cannot really do a screen-print on the client and have it print on the server, yet another reason to create a report.

Comment: I am doing something close to that... I am drawing the page up using System.Drawing libraries then printing it using System.Drawing.Printing ... It is a page showing invoices and then an actual check at the bottom. I was hoping I wouldn't have to redo all that work, but guess I am going to have to.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590896/auto-print-without-dialog and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572420/how-to-skip-the-dialog-of-printing-in-printdocument-print-and-print-page-direc

These two links should help you.

You could also consider saving them to the server as files instead of printing and print them later manually, depending on how critical printing actually is to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: thanks @Prospector, some of those examples will prove to be helpful... unfortunately the boss does not want files involved in this process, so i am creating the graphics and sending it straight to the printer.