# How print document in blazor without dialog?

Tags: printing, blazor

I have pdf file which I need to print.

I use PrintingService for blazor, but it call dialog for printing. How I can not show this or post confirm answer programly?

Comment: Also looking for such functionality. Did you solve it?

Comment: @Alex, yeah, I find. But not with browser standarts funcs. I printing document in back, like in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590896/auto-print-without-dialog