# How can I skip the print dialog?

Tags: c#

I have a button click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        string query = "INSERT INTO bank_check_kassa OUTPUT INSERTED.formatted_id default values";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        string insertedID = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
        label1.Padding = new Padding(-50, 0, 0, 0);
        label1.Text = "Novbedeki siraniz " + insertedID.ToString();

        // Printer ayarları
        using (PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument())
        {
            // Yazdırma işlemi
            pd.PrintPage += (s, args) => ProvideContent1(s, args, insertedID);
            pd.Print();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}

private void ProvideContent1(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e, string insertedID)
{
    // Создание шрифта для текста
    Font font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular);

    // Создание кисти для текста
    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

    // Определение координаты для вывода текста
    float x = 100;
    float y = 100;

    // Вывод текста на документ
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Novbedeki siraniz: " + insertedID, font, brush, x, y);
}
```

This works, in that information on the label will appear. However, I want to print the information *immediately,* and for some reason it doesn't go to print. Instead, I see the print dialog. What I want is to mark the printer by default so that the test can print without waiting (skip the dialog).

How can I do this?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: fwiw, it's usually a mistake to try to re-use the same connection object. ADO.Net already does connection pooling. Re-using the connection object interferes with that and makes things slower, rather than helping. You're better off allocating new connection objects for each query in a `using` block. If it's more about hiding the connection string, you can do that by making a method to return the newly-created connection. I also suggest closing the connection before moving on to printing.

Comment: Are you asking how to print something to the default system printer? Or otherwise predetermine the printer to use so that there's no user interaction required after clicking the button?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590896/auto-print-without-dialog